# raster lines with Bresenham algorithm (HTML5)

Tags: html

i have to develop a raster system of lines through the Bresenham algorithm in html environment. Due to the fact that I  recently started the use of HTML language, could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to show us what you have tried so far for us to be able to help you.

Comment: the problem is that I do not know where to start :(